# The screen is black when the iOS program is running from backgroud

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

[image: The program is running]

[image: Stay for a few of minutes and continue to run the program,the screen is black now]

The above run in Simulator, but run in iPhone is black too.

Comment: Add some description about your problem.

Comment: When the program stay one of views for a few  minutes. Then continue to run  the program.Now the screen is black.This is run in simulator.iPhone is black too.The above of images is about views.

Comment: Please show some code for this window. What is the code trying to do? Is the console saying anything?

Comment: [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = (null);

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved this problem. Please look at the following：

1. Because the session time is set in my project.When the program runs for 10 minutes, it will reset the rootViewController.And I use
   the snippet keys to set the rootViewController. Please see the image.

   [image: Screenshot]
2. When my project was running after iOS 10, I found that the code was to set up and control was changed.

   ```
   UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController =
           story.instantiateInitialViewController;
   ```

   This is a wrong way.
3. So I use a way of Tool Class to encapsulates.